# angularsjs ng-repeat sorting table with unkown amount of columns

Tags: javascript, sorting, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to sort a table by each column. The table has a different amount of rows and columns each time. The problem is with the predicate. All of the repeated columns are name "i", and I need to be able to sort them individually.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate='value';reverse=!reverse">name</a></th>
        <th ng-repeat="header in headers"><a href="" ng-click="predicate='i';reverse=!reverse">{{header}}</a></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="v in columns | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
            <td>{{v.value}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="i in v.item">{{i}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
function controller($scope) {
    $scope.headers = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"];
    $scope.columns = [{value:'row1', item:['1','2','3','4']},
                      {value:'row2', item:['4','5','6','7']},
                      {value:'row3', item:['8','9','10','11']},
                      {value:'row4', item:['12','13','14','15']}];
    $scope.predicate = 'value';
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sPUaw/3/).

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: The built in `orderBy` doesn't work for nested data like you've got. You'll have to create your own filter that is customized for the data you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the statement like this

```
<th ng-repeat="header in headers">
     <a href="" ng-click="$parent.predicate='item['+$index+']';$parent.reverse=!reverse">{{header}</a>
</th>
```

**Note**: Since the cells are all strings, this will sort all columns as string alphabetically.

Hope it can shed some light on.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T4xpH/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, works great. I knew it had something to do with $index but I just couldn't find the correct place to insert it. Appreciate it! And yeah, the data is in json for the actual app so I don't think that they will be in string format.